# How to get Share link from dropbox in swift

Tags: swift, swiftydropbox

Hey i am try to get the share link from drop box but it only works fro first time second time it through error shared_link_already_exist. please help me to how to get that share link. Thanks For the Help

here is my code

```
func GetPath(shortPath:String) {
  DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient?.sharing.createSharedLinkWithSettings(path: shortPath).response(queue: .main, completionHandler: { (response, error) in
        if let link = response {
            print(link.url)

        } else {
            print(error!)           

        }
    })


}
```

Comment: you can list previously shared links https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/SharingRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox13SharingRoutes15listSharedLinksFT4pathGSqSS_6cursorGSqSS_10directOnlyGSqSb__GCS_10RpcRequestCCS_7Sharing31ListSharedLinksResultSerializerCS2_30ListSharedLinksErrorSerializer_

Comment: Thanks Leo  its working  :)